# Can I manually add arbitrary css rules into my tailwind V1 bundle?

Tags: tailwind-css

I have a tailwind.config.js file and I would just like to append a few hand crafted CSS rules to the bundle it creates, rather than packaging them into a separate CSS file and importing it.

I'm stuck with tailwind V1 for the next month or two (it's a work thing) and all the info I'm finding by googling is for V2 and V3 so I'm struggling to get an answer to even simple questions like this! :/

How / where can I manually add styles please?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, turns out it's very simple, there's a `styles.css` file you can add whatever you like to!